# Como eliminar a string null da tag td?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Como retirar o "null" da tag  ?

Tentei usar o replace, mas ocorre erro devido a variável ser nula: 
Exemplo:

```
_st_versao_ofertada.replace("null","");  //Ná pode, ocorre erro. Como fazer ? <br>
```

**Erro:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
```

**Trecho do código:**

```
<table id="tbl_1">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Versão atual</td><td>Versão Ofertada</td><td>Versão Vendida</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-st_versao_atual="Plus">Plus</td><td data-st_versao_ofertada=""></td><td data-st_versao_vendida ='" + _st_versao_vendida + "'>King</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-st_versao_atual="King">King</td><td data-st_versao_ofertada="King"></td><td  data-st_versao_vendida ="King">King</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-st_versao_atual="King">King</td><td>King</td><td  data-st_versao_vendida ="Plus">Plus</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

var table_1 = $("#tbl_1 > tbody");

var _st_versao_atual = "";
var _st_versao_ofertada = "";
var _st_versao_vendida = "";
var html = "";

table_1.find("tr").each(function () {                
_st_versao_atual = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-st_versao_atual]').data('st_versao_atual');
_st_versao_ofertada = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-t_versao_ofertada]').data('st_versao_ofertada');
_st_versao_vendida = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-st_versao_vendida]').data('st_versao_vendida');

html = html + "<tr>";
html = html + "<td>" + _st_versao_atual + "</td>";
html = html + "<td>" + _st_versao_ofertada + "</td>";
html = html + "<td>" + _st_versao_vendida + "</td>";
html = html + "</tr>";
});

$("#tbl_2 > tbody").html(html);

<table id="tbl_2">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Versão atual</td><td>Versão Ofertada</td><td>Versão Vendida</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Plus</td><td>null</td><td>King</td>                     // <-- /Retirar ess Null
</tr>
<tr>
<td>King</td><td>null</td><td>King</td>                      // <-- /Retirar ess Null
</tr>
<tr>
<td>King</td><td>King</td><td>Plus</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<td data-st_versao_atual="King">King</td data-st_versao_ofertada="King">` [as tags finais não devem possuir atributos](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#end-tags)

Comment: não é mais fácil quando estiver gerando a tabela validar se o valor é null do que fazer um repalce depois?

Comment: Bom dia! @Augusto Vasques foi um erro ao colar as tags no editor, já corrigi  eu customizei o código para facilitar a visualização.

Comment: Bom dia! @Ricardo Pontual se você analisar verá que ao carregar a table a tag vem **vazia** daí então ao passar os dados da tbl_1 para a tbl_2 o campo vazio fica com a string `null`.

Comment: então, não pode antes de motar a string da tabela validar por exemplo  se `_st_versao_atual ` é null e mudar para ""?

Comment: Por que não faz algo como `if (_st_versao_atual == null) { escreva somente "<td></td>" } else { escreva o _st_versao_atual dentro do td }`?

Comment: Sim @Ricardo Pontual posso fazer if else como o hkotsubo sugeriu, porém a table possui 15 colunas e terei que fazer essa verificação para todas as colunas, vai ficar um pouco poluído, mas vejo que não tem outra alternativa de fazer isso com menos código.

Comment: Sempre que há código repetido ou algo que é feito muitas vezes com pouca variação, isso é sinal de que vc pode criar uma função e chamá-la em um loop :-)

Comment: não precisa de um `if` pra fazer isso, só usar um operador: `_st_versao_atual = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-st_versao_atual]').data('st_versao_atual') || "";`  limpo, simples e pronto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode usar o `|| ''` no final de cada atribuição, assim quando for `null` vai gerar uma valor `falsy` e vai colocar o `''` no lugar.

```
_st_versao_atual = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-st_versao_atual]').data('st_versao_atual') || '';
_st_versao_ofertada = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-t_versao_ofertada]').data('st_versao_ofertada') || '';
_st_versao_vendida = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-st_versao_vendida]').data('st_versao_vendida') || '';
```